# Choose fstream or cout depending on attributes

Tags: c++, c++11, stream

If there is `argv[1]` I want to put some data to new `ofstream(argv[1])` i.e file with name `argv[1]`. But if there are no such argument I want to use `cout` instead.

I've tried

```
std::ostream& output = argc >= 1 ? std::fstream(argv[0]) : std::cout;
```

But it even doesn't compile because of deleted constructor.

Comment: Try without making the `fstream` a temporary.

Comment: Besides, why not just go with output redirection? All OSes I can think of support it, and you get it for free using `cout`.

Comment: @zneak: How can I create it not temporary if there is no arg ?

Comment: And I have to use interface that allows to put filename in args

Comment: You are trying to get a reference to a temporary value, that's why it's not working. You cannot get a reference to a temporary value. It's like trying to do `double& d = sin(1)`.

Comment: I've heard something about objects, available throw refernce live longer ( up to next '}'). I'm not sure in details. Anyway, there is good solution in answers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create an fstream instance and delay opening it until necessary.

```
std::fstream file;
if (argc > 1)
    file.open(argv[1]);

std::ostream& output = argc > 1 ? file : std::cout;
```

Comment: +1 Upvoted, this is a nice, understandable solution. Nevertheless, you can avoid creating the `fstream` if it is not needed, and also the slight code duplication: branching on `argc>1` twice. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a truly C++11 solution:

```
ostream& out = [=]() -> ostream& {
    if (argc>1) {
        static fstream fs(argv[1]);
        return fs;
    }
    return cout;
}();
```

Comment: I like C++11, but I don't like this!

Comment: @JohnZwinck Yes, I upvoted the accepted answer and Bo's answer as well.

Comment: @JohnZwinck One thing is nice about lambdas in this respect: I can initialize const objects even if their initialization is complicated. And I like it!

Answer (score 2):

<strike>You cannot use a ternary operator with different types. The compiler cannot decide what type the result should have.</strike>

You could try

```
if (argc >= 1)
{
    std::fstream   Output(argv[0]);
    Process_data(Output);
}
else
    Process_data(std::cout);
```

Comment: I don't think your first sentence is accurate.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore It's partly correct, but that's only when the compiler can't resolve the two types to the same base type. In this case, `std::fstream` descends from `std::ostream` so it is in fact valid.

Comment: It might also have to do with creating  a temporary to bind to the reference. Streams being non-copyable and all.

Comment: @BoPersson the missing `const` is definitely an issue, yes, but not the only one.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore In that case the compiler is implicitly casting the integer `1` to a float and then implicitly converting back to int. You can verify by looking at `sizeof(true ? 0.2f : 1)` vs `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(float)`.

Comment: @KurtStutsman yes, I know. It was a counter-example to "but that's **only** when the compiler can't resolve the two types to the same base type."

Comment: +1 I like this solution because it avoids creating the `fstream` if not needed. It also avoids the code duplication: the condition `argc>1` is only check once as it is supposed to be.